# PhpStorm - Duplicate lines down not working correctly

Tags: phpstorm, phpstorm-2018.1

Duplicating lines does not work properly, e.g. if I try to duplicate the lines in the following screenshot:

[image]

then I get this:

[image]

instead of this:

[image]

Is there a setting so I can change this behaviour so that it works just like in NetBeans?

Comment: The duplication works perfectly, it can be seen in the images you posted. Make sure your selection contains complete lines and the duplicate command will produce what you want. Move the mouse cursor over the gutter (where the line numbers are displayed) and drag it there up or down to select complete lines.

Comment: @axiac, Im not sure what you are seeing. The duplication fails as you can see in the second screenshot. It should look like in the last screenshot.

Comment: It works correctly. The selection, clearly visible in all images, does not contain the end-of-line character after `</frontend>`. Select complete lines as explained above and it works as you expect. Or use the "Reformat Code" (from the "Code" menu) after the duplication and it will also look as you want.

Comment: You don't understand. I expected it to work exactly as in NetBeans. I just want to duplicate the lines down and it should instantly look like in the last screenshot. It should be like Screenshot 1 -> Screenshot 3. I hope that was clear.

Comment: It is clear for me, it is not clear for you. The last line in the screenshots you posted is not selected completely but you expect PhpStorm read your mind and add a newline after your selection. It doesn't work this way. Have you tried to select the complete line as I described above? The blue background of the selection must not end after `</frontend>` on the last line but fill the entire line, the same way it fills the lines above it.

Comment: @axiac, Sorry, but I think you don't understand anything. Did you even used NetBeans once? I don't think so. If NetBeans can "read my mind" then why should PhpStorm not be able to?

I know that I could place the cursor in the next line but I want it to work like in NetBeans which can "read my mind"...

Comment: A line is made up of the characters you see in the editor plus an invisible end-of-line character. Your selection contains 10 complete lines and some more characters that do not form a complete line. You can, as well, select only `   </front` on the last line. Does NetBeans automatically inserts a newline after the selection in this case? I bet it doesn't. And this is because NetBeans does not insert a non-existing newline into your selection; it probably reformats the code after the duplication.

Comment: @Black 1) You are using PhpStorm and not NetBeans. 2) Axiac is correct -- you have not selected the end-of-line symbol, therefore selection is duplicated as is. 3) Please note: you are using `Duplicate selection` action and not `Duplicate Lines`. If selection is made -- it duplicates **selection** (which does not include end-of-line/line ending in your case); if no selection is made -- it duplicates current line. Full stop. 4) Select last line in full (so it covers the line from start to end) and it will duplicate as you wish.

Comment: @LazyOne 1) If NetBeans can do this, then why can't PhpStorm do this too?! All I asked was if it is possible to change a Setting so that it behaves just like in NetBeans. See the last sentence of my question? I quote it for you: "Is there a setting so I can change this behaviour so that it works just like in NetBeans?"

Comment: @Black My apologies -- have not noted that part (the final line/question) -- it's barely visible on the overall post content (one line of text following by the image) + switched to reading comments. making it bold would help to be more visible. **The actual question** -- No; there is no such option (to auto reformat code after such operation) and you will have to make "proper" selection (to include whole lines) to have desired behaviour.

Comment: Ok, im sorry too for raging a bit. lol. Thanks for your help guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a setting so I can change this behaviour so that it works just like in NetBeans?

For "Duplicate **Selection**" action (which is what you are using) -- No; there is no such option (to auto reformat code after such operation or whatnot) and you will have to make "proper" selection (to include whole lines) to have desired behaviour.

Currently this action (Duplicate Selection) behaves correctly: it duplicates only selected text and nothing else.

But .. you can use "Duplicate **Entire Lines**" action instead ... which will duplicate WHOLE lines where selection is present (even if it's only one character selected on that line).

Just assign desired shortcut and use where needed.

- `Settings/Preferences | Keymap`
- Type `duplicate` into local search box to narrow possible results
- Locate `Editor Actions | Duplicate Entire Lines` in those results

[image]